# Call MySQL Stored Procedure with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Trying to get to grips with stored procedures in MySQL/PHP.  The SP works fine from the MySQL Console.

But trying to call it in PHP, I get the following:

`Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /home/dir/public_html/system/classes/account.class on line 92`

```
try {
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost';
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'usrName', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL db_name.stprNewUser(?,@statusValue)");
//$stmt->bindParam(1, 'user@googlemail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR); // <<LINE 92 DID NOT WORK
$stmt->bindValue(1, 'user@googlemail.com', PDO::PARAM_STR); // <<LINE 92 DID WORK

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

From [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

> If you don't know if you need bindValue() or bindParam(), go for the former. bindValue() is less ambiguous and has lesser side effects.

Comment: Thanks, that with Google / http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php helped.